# Points and segments

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search

I'm doing online course and got stuck at this problem.

The first line contains two non-negative integers 1 ≤ n, m ≤ 50000 — the number of segments and points on a line, respectively. The next n lines contain two integers a_i ≤ b_i defining the i-th segment. The next line contain m integers defining points. All the integers are of absolute value at most 10^8. For each segment, output the number of points it is used from the `n`-points table.

My solution is :

```
for point in points:
    occurrence = 0
    for l, r in segments:
        if l <= point <= r:
           occurrence += 1
    print(occurrence),
```

The complexity of this algorithm is O(m*n), which is obviously not very efficient. What is the best way of solving this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Sample Input:

```
2 3
0 5
7 10
1 6 11
```

Sample Output:

```
1 0 0
```

Sample Input 2:

```
1 3
-10 10
-100 100 0
```

Sample Output 2:

```
0 0 1
```

Comment: Can you describe problem in more details? What is input for the problem and what should be an output?

Comment: @Farseer I added sample IO

Comment: I've written a simple solution using `binary search` solving it in O(n log m). Check that.

Comment: @user1806258 your text does no match samples ... yor answer should be how many points are used in each segment not the other way around that is solvable in `O(m)` if I do not miss something ... you should repair your text if it is true if not repair the samples ... anyway you got both solution variations in my answer ... see also the comment so you know exactly what I mean

Comment: @Spektre the answer should be "for each point, output the number of segments it is contained in".

Comment: @user1806258 in that case the results are too big as you got 2 points and 3 output numbers ... 1 point and 3 output numbers

Comment: @Sperktre Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) to solve this problem.

First, break each segment into two points, open and close points.

Add all these points together with those `m` points, and **sort** them based on their locations.

Iterating through the list of points, maintaining a `counter`, every time you encounter an open point, increase the `counter`, and if you encounter an end point, decrease it. If you encounter a point in list `m` point, the result for this point is the value of `counter` at this moment.

```
For example 2, we have:

1 3
-10 10
-100 100 0

After sorting, what we have is:

-100 -10 0 10 100

At point -100, we have `counter = 0`

At point -10, this is open point, we increase `counter = 1`

At point 0, so result is 1

At point 10, this is close point, we decrease `counter = 0`

At point 100, result is 0

So, result for point -100 is 0, point 100 is 0 and point 0 is 1 as expected.
```

Time complexity is **O((n + m) log (n + m))**.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, in sample output 2 your algorithm would print 0 1 0 instead of 0 0 1

Comment: @user1806258 added an example, to recover back to original order, you just need to add some attribute or use a map, it is trivial, you can figure it out easily, so I don't include it in my solution.

Comment: @PhamTrung You are clearly know what is this really all about so I  have just few silly questions:  1. you are referring to each integer as to a single point? 2. what is the meaning of point index outside point table? 3. why are you mixing point table indexes and point coordinates together? It just does not make any sense to me at all (in respect to OP text)

Comment: @Spektre Hmm,  what I am referring to in my example is the coordinates of the point, I think this is the source of your confusion :)

Comment: @Pham Trung Thank you so much! I got it!

Comment: I appreciate your example as it makes your explanation a lot clearer

Comment: I understood the explanation you gave. But still I had some doubts. What should we do if there are duplicate values of integers in the coordinates of line segments and in the points to be searched?
for ex. 
1 3
-10 10
-100 10 0 

how should I go for such test case??

Answer (score 1):

**[Original answer] by how many segments is each point used**

I am not sure I got the problem correctly but looks like simple example of Histogram use ...

1. **create counter array** (one item per point)
2. **set it to zero**
3. **process the last line incrementing each used point counter `O(m)`**
4. **write the answer by reading histogram `O(n)`**

So the result should be `O(m+n)` something like (C++):

```
const int n=2,m=3;
const int p[n][2]={ {0,5},{7,10} };
const int s[m]={1,6,11};
int i,cnt[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++) cnt[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<m;i++) if ((s[i]>=0)&&(s[i]<n)) cnt[s[i]]++;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) cout << cnt[i] << " "; // result: 0 1
```

But as you can see the `p[]` coordinates are never used so either I missed something in your problem description or you missing something or it is there just to trick solvers ...

**[edit1] after clearing the inconsistencies in OP the result is a bit different**

**By how many points is each segment used:**

1. **create counter array** (one item per segment)
2. **set it to zero**
3. **process the last line incrementing each used point counter `O(m)`**
4. **write the answer by reading histogram `O(m)`**

**So the result is `O(m)` something like (C++):**

```
const int n=2,m=3;
const int p[n][2]={ {0,5},{7,10} };
const int s[m]={1,6,11};
int i,cnt[m];
for (i=0;i<m;i++) cnt[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<m;i++) if ((s[i]>=0)&&(s[i]<n)) cnt[i]++;
for (i=0;i<m;i++) cout << cnt[i] << " "; // result: 1,0,0
```

**[Notes]**

After added new sample set to OP it is clear now that:

- indexes starts from `0`
- the problem is how many points from table `p[n]` are really used by each segment (`m` numbers in output)

Comment: What is your `m` array?

Comment: You have written `cnt[m[i]]++`. What is `m[i]`? `m` is an `int` variable.

Comment: @vish4071 lol I am thyping like an Ape today .. still have not got mine Morning tea it should be `s[]` of coarse now should be thypo free

Comment: OK. But still, s[1] = 6. Your `cnt[]` is of size 2.

Comment: `if` is ok. But `cnt[s[1]] = cnt[6]`. But `cnt` is of size 2.

Comment: In that case, `cnt` needs to be of size `10^8` or you can use map.

Comment: @vish4071 the if (s[i]<n) will prevent to execute that ... it is only acounting the points present in a list ... `6,11,`is ignored Also if you are using conventions that indexing is not from zero then you need to add +1/-1 to handle that but you did not specify ... but your sample is suggesting that ... just spotted that

Comment: @vish4071 have changed the code to handle your point indexing from 1 instead of 0. (increase the counter size by1 and writing the answer from 1 not 0)

Comment: @vish4071 Why should be cnt of that big size when the numbers above are not used anyway ... see your sample output there is no output for 6,11 only (1,0,0) which is a bit suspicious as you got only 2 points which contradicts your problem description. You have to write how many segments use which point not the other way around ... at least that is in your OP text ... as I wrote I am not sure I get your statement right as the input sample does not match text ...

Comment: The point can be 10^8. Can it be not? In that case, as you are incrementing `cnt[s[i]]`, you are incrementing `cnt[10^8]`. Or better still, use map.

Comment: @vish4071 not at all as the line is `if (s[i]<n) cnt[s[i]]++;` the counter is incremented only if the point accounted is inside your point table. But you should  really clear what is wrong in your Question because text suggest answer with `1` number per point in point table (n) and your sample result is `m` numbers so something is fishy somewhere ...

Comment: @vish4071 so if your samples are correct then the text is wrong and you should rewrite it that you need the count of points used by each segments instead of count of segments used by points

Comment: Oh. I think you got the question wrong. It is asking, of all the available segments, (number of) which segments are such that they hold the point. eg. A segment that stretches from 12 to 18 will contain all points from (12,13,...18).

Comment: Its not my question buddy :) . I am just an interested one :)

Comment: @vish4071 ow sorry I see now :) ... have added edit to my answer ... I go for my tea it should be ready by now :)

Comment: @Spektre I have added another sample IO. You algorithm will print 1 0 1 instead of 0 0 1

Comment: @user1806258 that is because you input negative values as input and does state in OP that there will not be negative values ... just add another if ... will edit shortly

Comment: @user1806258 ow you can have negative values I wrongly translated ... both codes are repaired

Answer (score 1):

Use Binary Search.

Sort the line segments according to 1st value *and* the second value. If you use `c++`, you can use custom sort like this:

```
sort(a,a+n,fun);    //a is your array of pair<int,int>, coordinates representing line

bool fun(pair<int,int> a, pair<int,int> b){
    if(a.first<b.first)
        return true;
    if(a.first>b.first)
        return false;
    return a.second < b.second;
}
```

Then, for every point, find the 1st line that captures the point and the first line that does not (after the line that does of course). If no line captures the point, you can return -1 or something (and not check for the point that does not).

Something like:

```
int checkFirstHold(pair<int,int> a[], int p,int min, int max){     //p is the point

    while(min < max){
        int mid = (min + max)/2;
        if(a[mid].first <= p && a[mid].second>=p && a[mid-1].first<p && a[mid-1].second<p)   //ie, p is in line a[mid] and not in line a[mid-1]
            return mid;
        if(a[mid].first <= p && a[mid].second>=p && a[mid-1].first<=p && a[mid-1].second>=p)   //ie, p is both in line a[mid] and not in line a[mid-1]
            max = mid-1;
        if(a[mid].first < p && a[mid].second<p )   //ie, p is not in line a[mid]
            min = mid + 1;
    }
return -1; //implying no point holds the line
}
```

Similarly, write a checkLastHold function.

Then, find `checkLastHold - checkFirstHold` for every point, which is the answer.

The complexity of this solution will be O(n log m), as it takes (log m) for every calculation.

Comment: Wow just noticed the rep drop so It must be me but I do not remember clicking on it and I scroll with wheel so it should not be miss click also..(unless I hit it while going between C++ ide and Opera that is most likely). have to wait ~30mins to negate .. sorry

Comment: My vote is locked (not sure why ... ) please make an edit so I can up vote back

Answer (score 0):

Here is my counter-based solution in Java.
Note that all points, segment start and segment end are read into one array.

If points of different `PointType` have the same x-coordinate, then the point is sorted after segment start and before segment end. This is done to count the point as "in" the segment if it coincides with both the segment start (counter already increased) and the segment end (counter not yet decreased).

For storing an answer in the same order as the points from the input, I create the array `result` of size `pointsCount` (only points counted, not the segments) and set its element with index `SuperPoint.index`, which stores the position of the point in the original input.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class PointsAndSegmentsSolution {

    enum PointType { // in order of sort, so that the point will be counted on both segment start and end coordinates
        SEGMENT_START,
        POINT,
        SEGMENT_END,
    }

    static class SuperPoint {
        final PointType type;
        final int x;
        final int index; // -1 (actually does not matter) for segments, index for points

        public SuperPoint(final PointType type, final int x) {
            this(type, x, -1);
        }

        public SuperPoint(final PointType type, final int x, final int index) {
            this.type = type;
            this.x = x;
            this.index = index;
        }
    }

    private static int[] countSegments(final SuperPoint[] allPoints, final int pointsCount) {
        Arrays.sort(allPoints, (o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1.x < o2.x)
                return -1;

            if (o1.x > o2.x)
                return 1;

            return Integer.compare( o1.type.ordinal(), o2.type.ordinal() ); // points with the same X coordinate by order in PointType enum
        });

        final int[] result = new int[pointsCount];
        int counter = 0;

        for (final SuperPoint superPoint : allPoints) {
            switch (superPoint.type) {

                case SEGMENT_START:
                    counter++;
                    break;

                case SEGMENT_END:
                    counter--;
                    break;

                case POINT:
                    result[superPoint.index] = counter;
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException( String.format("Unknown SuperPoint type: %s", superPoint.type) );
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int segmentsCount = scanner.nextInt();
        final int pointsCount = scanner.nextInt();

        final SuperPoint[] allPoints = new SuperPoint[(segmentsCount * 2) + pointsCount];
        int allPointsIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < segmentsCount; i++) {
            final int start = scanner.nextInt();
            final int end = scanner.nextInt();

            allPoints[allPointsIndex] = new SuperPoint(PointType.SEGMENT_START, start);
            allPointsIndex++;

            allPoints[allPointsIndex] = new SuperPoint(PointType.SEGMENT_END, end);
            allPointsIndex++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
            final int x = scanner.nextInt();

            allPoints[allPointsIndex] = new SuperPoint(PointType.POINT, x, i);
            allPointsIndex++;
        }

        final int[] pointsSegmentsCounts = countSegments(allPoints, pointsCount);

        for (final int count : pointsSegmentsCounts) {
            System.out.print(count + " ");
        }
    }
}
```